# Activity with fragments - why dont fragments get paused

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have an activity with 3 fragments in it: all 3 fragments are listviews

I click a button and that activity should get paused, when a new activity opens on top of it

the new activity has another listview

my question is, why when i scroll through the listview of the new activity, the listviews of the fragments of the paused activity also get scrolled, thus calling their getView methods ?

Comment: You need to provide some code. You **should not** make a general assumption (i.e., _"Fragments are not paused when parent activity is paused"_) about all fragment implementations just because your code is behaving as such.

Comment: how do i pause a fragment manually ? to prevent their getView being called, when they are not visible on the screen

there is are 20 files to this code, i dont know which ones make it do that

Comment: I put a toast in the fragment's on pause - and it gets called before the onPause of the activity gets called - but i am guessing i am missing the necessary code to pause the fragment

Comment: how do i pause a  listview?